# How to get the event information and have it display in a tooltip in FullCalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

To further explain,

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin (http://fullcalendar.io/). And whenever I hover over an event, I want the event information(title, date, time etc.) to be displayed in a tooltip.

I kinda got it working, but only the event title is showing.

How can I make the Date and Time to show as well?

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here

        height: 'auto',
        timeFormat: 'h:mm',
        /*eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
            window.location = "http://www."
        }*/

        events: [
            {
                title : 'Pizza Cooking Class',
                start : '2015-11-12T09:00', // Year, Month, Day + Time
                color : '#00adef', // Label color
                textColor : '#FFF', // Text color
                category : '1',
                url : 'cookingclass.php'
            }
        ],
        eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view ) {
        return ['all', event.category].indexOf($('#category-select').val()) >= 0
        },  

        eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:200px;height:50px;background:#fff;position:absolute;z-index:10001; padding:20px; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
            $("body").append(tooltip);
            $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
                $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
            }).mousemove(function(e) {
                $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
            });
        },

        eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 8);
            $('.tooltipevent').remove();
        }

    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var jsDate = new Date(jsEvent.timeStamp * 1000);
    console.log(jsDate.toDateString())
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:200px;height:50px;background:#fff;position:absolute;z-index:10001; padding:20px; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">' + calEvent.title + '<br>' + jsDate.toDateString() + '</div>';
    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
}
```

Try this one.

Comment: Hey awesome man, your answer is able to get the date and time! But the date and time are wrong, they're not the event's date and time. Sorry but how do I make it get the correct date and time? Thanks again! Really appreciate it!

Comment: calEvent.start will be the start date/time of the event. fullcalendar's site [has an example](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) of using qtip2 to do tooltips as well [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m54g5aen/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got it working now using "calEvent.start". Very much appreciated. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I used the code given in the answer from @guradio but found that the tooltip was only displayed when over the text of event.

[image: Popup only activated over event text]

I modified the code to the following which seems to work well and the tooltip is triggered when the mouse enters any part of the event.

```
eventMouseover : function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    $('.tooltipevent').remove();
    var tt = $(getTooltip(calEvent));
    $("body").append(tt);
    $(tt).hide();
    $(tt).fadeTo('1000', 0.9);
    $(tt).position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: $(this),
        collision: "fit"
    });
},

eventMouseout : function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    $('.tooltipevent').remove();
}
```